# How to fix loose uPVC door sill?

Tags: doors, door-frame, sill

Outside our front door we have a "sill". Both the door and sill are uPVC. The sill is loose (has been since we moved in) - I have no idea how it was ever held into place, if it ever was - it just comes out very easily if you pull it (or step on it). The photos show the sill in place, and then removed. In the last two photos I'm trying to show what's inside the gap where the sill sits.

How can I secure the sill back in place, so it doesn't move and can be stepped on?

[image: Sill in place]

[image: Sill out]

[image: Shot 1 of gap]

[image: Shot 2 of gap]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was just glued on.

With it so wide with no support under the outer edge, coming loose is almost a guarantee.

Would either cut it to size(maybe under a inch past the bricks), or make a support to hold it up.

Clean surfaces and re-glue.

Comment: Make sure that "clean surfaces" includes the gap into which the sill sits. Get all the dust, dirt and debris out of that gap to ensure it glues in securely, as anything loose in there will simply come out attached to the adhesive.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks. Any particular type of glue? For cutting it - lengthwise it fits neatly (see first photo) so presumably not necessary?

Comment: It is just how far out it stands with no support.  Everytime it is stepped on it will loosen, also can be a tripping hazard walking in, a foot catches under it.  Probably would use an exterial construction adhesive.  Clean all surfaces of dirt and old glue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the fitter was wearing a stetson & 6-shooter. That is a cowboy job if ever I saw one.
They shouldn't have put full surround on, fitted like it was a window with a frame to trip over every time you cross the threshold... & no-one in their right mind would overhang a plastic sill like that with no support.
It should have had a flat-seal threshold & a weather bar [also conspicuously missing] so rain can't happily pee down the door & run inside if you open it, or even whilst it's closed, once the seal has been kicked enough times to no longer be water-tight.

Assuming you're still going to be stepping over that ridiculous frame every time you enter or leave - as to replace it would mean the entire door & frame (or put a spacer in the top of the frame) - consider whether to just shorten the sill & gob it in with 'foam & fill', or put brickwork under to make a proper step out of it.

Either way, you cannot leave it just floating like that, it will last minutes. If you glue it hard enough, the sill will snap off rather than fall out next time.